# Is it possible to make AWS EKS nodes (EC2 instances) automatically get an IP from a specific subnet (on the same VPC or another VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

We have an EKS cluster running in a VPC and we are thinking of extending this VPC or creating another VPC with a different subnet IP range. EKS nodes (EC2 instances) are running with multiple ENIs, that is, with multiple private IPs.

We wonder if it is possible to make these EC2 instances which serve as EKS nodes automatically get an IP from this new subnet within current VPC or on the other VPC when they are getting instantiated. If the subnet is on another VPC, should we have a VPC peering connection between two VPCs? Can it be doable by Cloud Formation templates on EKS? What is the best practice here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The option to extend VPC in EKS is via adding secondary CIDR block and configure CNI plugin to use the subnets created in the secondary CIDR block. CNI is ultimately responsible to assign the ip addresses available through the subnet cidr to the pods.

To use the correct CIDR range for VPC extension and to configure the CNI please use the below article :

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-multiple-cidr-ranges/

Comment: This article explains the problem using VPC expansion. What about defining another VPC and creating a subnet there? What needs to be done to enable EC2 instances in EKS cluster get an IP from newly created VPC?

Comment: I am not sure which article you are referring to  but AWS clearly says that to extend the ip address range for EKS cluster is via adding the secondary CIDR block. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html  . The clear instructions to add additional subnets in new CIDR & configure networking for them  is clearly explained in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-multiple-cidr-ranges/